# How to count the number of matches for a given string in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, regex

An existing database contains a field call "dependent_ages", and some example data looks like "1,2,5" or "1yo and 3mo" or "4mo".

The requirement is to convert such a string into an integer number, which is the number of substrings seperated by "," or "and". More precisely, the separator can be described as a regular expression ",|\sand\s". So for the above example the converted integers are 3, 2 and 1. Basically, I am interested in *how many* matches exists, not the *value* of those matches. So what ever the individual value is "14yo" or "4mo", it will be counted as 1.

The question is to find a MySQL expression that can do this, for example

```
SELECT REGEXMATCHES(dependent_ages) as dependent_no ...
```

**UPADTE**

Some answer/comments show some general misunderstand of the question so I clarified the question.

Comment: How does the example data result in integers 3, 2 and 1?

Comment: Natural languages are not regular and are generally not parsable by regex. That said, you could use `\d+` to extract all of the indepedent numbers (so from `14yr, 9yr` you'd get `14` and `9`). Of course, there's no way to differentiate between 9 years and 9 months.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 I think you didn't understand me. That field describes the ages of kids for a person, and what I want is the number of his/her kids. So whether the age is 14yr or 14mo or 15yo is irrelevant, all those will be counted as 1 kid.

Comment: @TomMac Please see my previous comment and my updated text.

Comment: You best bet is to fetch the data from SQL, use something like Perl to parse it (this may take some effort) and then put it into a more appropriate form for SQL to process. Alter the tables at this stage. IMHO SQL is **NOT** the appropriate tool to do this sort of thing.

Comment: @EdHeal I think you could be right. I am currently using Java to parse the data. I am just wondering weather a SQL solution exists.

Comment: @EarthEngine - I would imagine this is a one off exercise to get the data into a better format. As the text is strings you might have to fiddle with some manually. I would therefore use the Perl route for this as the SQL would be fiddly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
SELECT
  col,
  CASE WHEN COALESCE(col, '')='' THEN 0
  ELSE
    length(col)-length(replace(col, ',', ''))+
    (length(col)-length(replace(col, ' and ', ''))) DIV 5
    +1
  END
FROM
  yourtable
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e186/1).

Comment: This is a clever answer. However it is not using regular expression, so it works only on this example. What if more complicated patterns has been used? Anyway I +1 your answer.

Comment: And also this one is fail on input 'Torand:1yo,Tarkel:3mo'. According to the given regular expression it should return 2. Your code returns 3.

Comment: @EarthEngine I updated my answer, now it works on your input. Unfurtunately MySql support for regular expressions is very limited

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation for MySQL's [string functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html) and [Regular Expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html), I do not think it is possible to do anything more than return true (1) or false (0) using a regex comparison. You cannot return a match and you cannot return the number of matches. I don't think you can even use regex to perform a replace.

You might be able to use a [Stored Program](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-programs-defining.html):

- Starting with: `'son: 10yr * daughter: 5yr * son:6mo'`
- First Pass: replace all `"*"` within a string with `""` ==> `'son: 10yr  daughter: 5yr  son:6mo'`
- Second Pass: replace sequences of numbers with a `"*"` (so `"15"` becomes `"*"`) ==> `'son: *yr  daughter: *yr  son:*mo'`
- Third Pass: replace non-`"*"` with `""` ==> `'***'`
- Fourth Pass: return the length of the string (3).

It would be slow and combersome for a large number of records, but it'd keep you within MySQL. You might also want to consider using another tool to download the rows, do your processing, then upload the results.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly this is what you need.

```
select count(*) from `table` where `dependent_ages` rlike 'HERE-REGEX'
```

Comment: @EarthEngine - Perhaps you didn't ask very well on the first try? Your update is much clearer.